# Augmented reality Vuforia- What is a marker

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality, vuforia

im new to augmented reality but what is meant by the term marker ? i have done a web search and it says the marker is a place where content will be shown on the mobile device but im not clear still. Here is what i found out so far:

> Augmented reality is hidden content, most commonly hidden behind
>   marker images, that can be included in printed and film media, as long
>   as the marker is displayed for a suitable length of time, in a steady
>   position for an application to identify and analyze it. Depending on
>   the content, the marker may have to remain visible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TLDR: Augmented Reality markers ~= Google Goggles + Activator

AR markers can be real-world objects or locations that trigger associated actions in your AR system when identified in sight, and usually result in some action, like displaying annotations (à la Rap Genius for objects around you).

Example:

Imagine you are gazing through your AR glasses. (You will see both what is displayed on the lenses, if anything, as well as the world around you.)
As you drive by a series of road cones closing the rightmost lane ahead, the AR software analyzes the scene and identifies several road cones in formation. This pattern is programmed to launch traffic notification software and, in conjunction with your AR's built-in GPS, obtains the latest information regarding what is going on here and what to expect.

In this way, the road cone formation is a marker: something particular and pre-defined triggers some action: obtaining and providing special information regarding your surroundings.

Comment: No, this is not correct.  This person is asking about markers in the kind of AR done by Vuforia, what you describe is a generic use of the term that does not apply to AR where 3D graphics are registered with the real world

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of types of marker in Vuforia, there are ones you define yourself, after putting them in to they CMS online, ones that you can create at run time and set markers that just have information around the edge. They are where your content will appear. You can see a video here where my business card is the marker and the 3d content is rendered on top. http://youtu.be/MvlHXKOonjI

When the app sees the marker it will work out the pose (position and rotation) of the marker and apply that to any 3d content you want to load, that way as you move around date marker the content stays in the same relative position to the marker.

And one final heads up, this is much easier in Unity 3D than using the iOS or Android native versions. I've done quite a lot and it saves a lot of time.

Comment: This is not quite correct.  Vuforia uses the term Marker only in the context of their "frame Markers" which are black and white squares with a code embedded around the edge.  They use the term "target" (I.e., image target, user-defined target, etc) for things that can be tracked by the software.

Comment: Btw, unity is easier if what you want to do is a good match for Unity (ie, build an app that is entirely 3d or custom content).  But if you want to integrate AR into a more general app, where you take advantage of the iOS or android platform capabilities, native is better.

Answer (score 1):

Marker is nothing but a target for your Augmented Reality app. Whenever you see your marker through the AR CAMERA, the models of your augmented reality app will be shown on!

It will be easy to understand if you develop your first app in augmented reality! :)